# Image catalogue of the Pegasus-PaaS Manager generic enabler of FIWARE

Tags: fiware, fiware-pegasus

Where can I check the image catalogue available for fiware-paas (Pegasus) to choose my virtual machine to GE deployed from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login into the FIWARE Cloud Portal with your credentials. Press on *Cloud link* on top, then you should see a menu to the left and go to *Compute->Images*.

All the images available in the FIWARE Catalog will be displayed. You can always deploy a VM from any of the images by pressing the *Lauch* bottom that appears at the right side of the images.